# Can you capture image after few seconds?

Tags: camera, libgphoto2

Is there some parameter for gphoto2 command to take picture after x seconds?
I tried to use -I 5 and -F 1, but it took picture immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is: `--wait-event SECONDS, MILLISECONDS, COUNT or MATCHSTRING`

Check out the gphoto2 reference page:
http://www.gphoto.org/doc/manual/ref-gphoto2-cli.html

This will capture an image after 5 seconds

```
gphoto2 --wait-event=5s --capture-image
```